# How to write an ingress-controller target-rewrite rule in my example?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am not very familiar with ingress but I am playing around with it.

My goal is to write a target-rewrite policy that redirects all traffic for the /application path to the correct / path were the service is listening.

I came up with the following ingress definition

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: application-ingress
  namespace: myapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /application
spec:
  rules:
 - host: myhost.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-service
          servicePort: 8080
  tls:
 - secretName: myapp-cert
```

But when applied, browsing to *myhost.foo.com/application* doesn't redirect the traffic to the root path where the service is listening. It simply times out.

But, if I remove the traffic-rewrite statement and simply browse to *myhost.foo.com*, then it works, so it's not a problem with the service being incorrectly configured.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it works in exactly the opposite way. Your exzmple would make sense if your application was listening on `/application`, in other words if it had its root path at `/application` rather than at `/`, all requests sent to `/` would be redirected to `/application`. Check the example [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#app-root).

As you can see [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#deployment):

> `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root` annotation *defines the
> Application Root that the Controller must redirect if it's in '/'
> context*.

In your example you've defined only access path at `/`, in other words it works only when you're accessing your app at `myhost.foo.com`. You didn't mention anywhere in your ingress definition that it might be accesst at other paths like `/application` so `myhost.foo.com/application` have no chances to work.

If you rather want to be able to access your app at `myhost.foo.com/application` you need something like below:

```
spec:
  rules:
 - host: myhost.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /application
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

but without a rewrite it will send any request to your backend `Pod`, exposed by your `myapp-service` `Service` not to its `/` but to `/application` as you're accessing your ingress backend via this particular path.

To solve that you need a [rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite). As you can read in the documentation:

> In some scenarios the exposed URL in the backend service differs from
> the specified path in the Ingress rule. Without a rewrite any request
> will return 404. Set the annotation
> `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` to the path expected by the
> service.

Following [this example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#examples) your ingress definition may look as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /application(/|$)(.*)
```

> In this ingress definition, any characters captured by (.*) will be
> assigned to the placeholder $2, which is then used as a parameter in
> the rewrite-target annotation.

The ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites:

`myhost.foo.com/application` rewrites to `myhost.foo.com/`

`myhost.foo.com/application/` rewrites to `myhost.foo.com/`

`myhost.foo.com/application/new` rewrites to `myhost.foo.com/new`

You can also try:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(.*)
```